# Looking for a Dutch CiviCRM basics manual or book

Tags: documentation

Is anyone aware of a book, document, customer manual or other Dutch material that could help customers in understanding and using the basic functionality (like searching, basic concepts ...) ?

Comment: I would like to start on the R2 wiki (r2.miraheze.org).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not Paul, but if you start writing let me know :-)